# Bivariate Normal Distribution with correlation of 0

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, correlation, bivariate-distributions

Data from a large population indicate that the heights of mothers and daughters in this population follow a bivariate normal distribution with correlation 0.5. Both the mothers and daughters have a mean height of 5 ft 4in with a standard deviation on 2 inches.

If the correlation between mother and daughter’s height were 0, ﬁnd the probability that both a mother and her daughter have height above average.

When I computed this I found that the probability would be 0.25 given the correlation is 0, but I am uncertain if this is right. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it is correct. For bivariate normal, zero correlation implies independence and hence the result holds trivially.

Comment: Thank you so much. And if the correlation was 0.5, I find that the probability that they are both above average height would be less when compared to the probability with correlation of 0. Do you agree?

Comment: No - with a bivariate normal  distribution and a positive correlation, the probability would be greater than $\frac14$

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but somehow my computations give me an answer that is less than 0.25.